# Button and Anchor tag hover & Active not working on Chrome in Iphone

Tags: ios, css, google-chrome, mobile

Desktop: When you hover in Button or Anchor Link, background color changed.
Mobile: The Hover or Active doesn't changed the background color.

```
.btn {
 background: transparent;
 color: #000;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:active {
 background: #bf0;
 color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Please look at [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please upload html code too

Comment: Hi Guys,

Thanks for quick reply,

My code is just a plain html

    <a class="btn" href="#">Click me!</a>
    <button class="btn">Click me!</button>

It works on Safari and Android devices. But not on IOS Chrome

Comment: In mobile You can't hover the thing its change its background color is through click

Comment: Yes, what i mean is even if you click the button, it doesn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code solved my problem

```
 document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){}, true)
```

Comment: Incredibly! Such a simple solution and I was looking for one for hours!